# How to insert ProgressBar for loading more items in Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am obtaining 50 items per API call and inserting it into `RecyclerView`. When I scroll to the end, I add a `ProgressBar` inside the last existing `ViewHolder` and displaying it instead of having a separate `ViewHolder` for the `ProgressBar`. But there are some performance issues. Can anybody tell me if my approach is right? I would appreciate if anyone can suggest me a correct method to do it

Comment: you can use viewtype in adapter to display loader viewtype

Comment: can you share your code how you are implementing it?

Comment: we can achieve this using the paging library. which will improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

For showing loader in recyler view in last you just have to create another view item for loader and override getItemViewType method of Recycler View , and pass this progress bar view ID ,based on your condition.

```java
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(YOUR_LIST(position))) {
        return PROGRESS_VIEW;
    } else {
        return ITEM_VIEW;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the Adapter class

```
  class AdapterClass(private var mList: MutableList<Any>?,
                     var  mContext: Context
                    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter< RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

private val DATA = 1
private val LOADER = 2

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return if (viewType == DATA) {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view, parent, false)
        Items(view)
    } else {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_loadmore, parent, false)
        ViewHolderLoader(view)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mList?.size?:0
}


override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return when {
        mList?.get(position) is DataItem -> DATA
        mList?.get(position) is Loader -> LOADER
        else -> DATA
    }
}



override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    if (holder?.itemViewType == DATA) {
        val viewHolder = holder as AdapterClass.Items
        val dataItem = mList?.get(position) as DataItem

        viewHolder.bindData(dataItem)
    }
}

inner class Items(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bindData(data: DataItem?) {
}
inner class ViewHolderLoader(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

}

Comment: Here DATA is your list type item and LOADER is a blank class for showing loader   only.

Answer (score 0):

a progress bar during the successive API call, which can be achieved using the android paging library.

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == DATA_VIEW_TYPE) NewsViewHolder.create(parent) else ListFooterViewHolder.create(retry, parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == DATA_VIEW_TYPE)
            (holder as NewsViewHolder).bind(getItem(position))
        else (holder as ListFooterViewHolder).bind(state)
    }
```

Based on the view type we can add the progress bar(indicate the next API call) at the end of the list.
please refer the https://medium.com/@sharmadhiraj.np/android-paging-library-step-by-step-implementation-guide-75417753d9b9